# I want zip file without any directories in zip file.How can I do in c#

Tags: c#, zip, compression, dotnetzip

My problem is that I want zip my file into zip formatted file. I used DotNetZib library works fine but there is a little problem in there. I read file from C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA for instance. But it creates full path which read from path given above in zip file.I want that when i clicked the zip file a.txt will be directly...Is there anyone to help me?

```
  using (ZipFile zip=new ZipFile())
        {

            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.Default;
            zip.AddItem(@"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a.txt");

            zip.Save(@"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\deneme.zip");
        }
```

This code block uses Ionic.Zip; dll and in zip file all path is there i want only a.txt will be in deneme.zip without any directions.Is this more useful to understand.If i wrote wrong sorry, my english is not very good.

Comment: You could copy files into temporal folder and then zip. But what would you do, if there are two files: `somefolder\a.txt` and `someotherfolder\a.txt` ?

Comment: Please show some code. So that we can get a clear picture of what you exactly want.

Comment: All right here is the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the ZipFile.AddItem method have another variant with two strings source file path and file path in archive.

You have to use :

```
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\Hüseyin\Desktop\AA\a.txt";
        zip.AddItem(filePath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

to put the a.txt file in the root directory of the zip file.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Works fine question is over.That is what i want o write in the code...A little correction has to be made in zip.AddItem function not filePath must be filepath i guess